# Apache2: redirect based on URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm on Apache2 and in directory "/demo". Inside this directory there is:

- v1/index.html
- v2/index.html

I want to redirect like this:

- "/demo", "/demo/" and "/demo/*" => v1/index.html
- "/demo/static", "/demo/static/" and "/demo/static/*" => v2/index.html

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static [NC]
RewriteRule .* v1/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} static [NC]
RewriteRule .* v2/index.html [L]
```

Anyone with an idea how to make this work?

Additional details:
Root directory is here: `/var/www/dev` and contains my directory *demo*. *.htaccess* is in inside the directory *demo*.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*demo/static.* v2/index.html [L] 
RewriteRule .*demo.* v1/index.html
```

Since I don't know what is the document root here, I used .*, so it can catch more than you want, but this can be a starting point.

Comment: I had to wait for the answer of the admin. Root directory is here: `/var/www/dev` and contains my directory _demo_. _.htaccess_ is in inside the directory _demo_.

Sorry, your code isn't working. I'm getting this error when trying to visit _example.com/demo/static: `The requested URL /demo/static was not found on this server.`

Comment: I think I know what happens: apache tries to redirect from v2 to v1. This seems to work, but it's very ugly: `RewriteRule demo v2/index.html [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !v2/index.html$
RewriteRule .* v1/index.html [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's a solution?

```
RewriteRule ^static/?$ v2/index.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ v1/index.html
```